# Estimating conditional probabilities on a large corpus of parsed documents

Tags: bayesian, estimation, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

### Scope

I have a large corpus of (parsed) documents where each has multiple terms *and* few associated codes.
My objective is to estimate the conditional probability $P(code | terms)$.

### First attempt

After some limited review of the literature, I prototyped a solution using a Bayesian network. 
First, I turned the corpus into a one-hot-encoded matrix $M$.
Next, using [`pgmpy`](https://pgmpy.org/), I estimated the DAG representing the network:

```py
from pgmpy.estimators import BicScore, HillClimbSearch
from pgmpy.inference import VariableElimination
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel

model_estimation = HillClimbSearch(data, scoring_method=BicScore(data))
estimated_model = model_estimation.estimate()
```

Next, I built a model, fitted it and instantiated a variable elimination object:

```py
bayes_model = BayesianModel(estimated_model.edges)
bayes_model.fit(ohe_corpus)
inference = VariableElimination(bayes_model)
```

At this point I could run something like:

```py
inference.query(["code_1", "code_2"], evidence=["term_i", "term_j", "term_k"])
```

which returns a table with the conditional probabilities.
This last step was very fast.

### Synthetic data

As the next phase, I created a synthetic data set and used the pipeline described above to experiment with it.
It comes as no surprise that the bottle neck of this approach is the model/DAG estimation phase.
Here are some timings I took:

```
duration_sec  n_codes  n_terms  related_terms_per_doc   noise_terms_per_doc  nodes_count
  141.957661        3       15                      6                     2           40
  178.062985        3       16                      6                     2           43
  904.152860        3       18                      6                     2           48
 1031.557014        3       20                      6                     2           52
 1040.274353        3       17                      6                     2           48
 1135.333175        3       19                      6                     2           52
```

- `n_codes` is the number of codes my corpus has
- `n_terms` is the number of terms my corpus has
- `related_terms_per_doc` is the number of terms related to the code of the document
- `noise_terms_per_doc` is the number of terms *not* related to the code of the document
- `nodes_count` the number of nodes in the estimated DAG.

In each test I had the same number of documents: 500.
For the sake of brevity, I skipped some details how I constructed the synthetic data.

This growth in time might turn to be an issue for my application.

### My questions

1. How feasible this approach is assuming I'm having about 50k documents using thousands of terms and hundreds of codes?
2. I understand that the complexity of the DAG estimation exponentially depends on the number of unique terms and codes in the corpus. Is that correct? I might be OK with an estimation step that takes 12-24 hours but I need to know about this in advance.
3. Assuming that the answers to the above questions are that it is rather impractical, what would be a workaround? One idea I had is to run a PCA on the correlation matrix of the one-hot-encoded terms data and build a DAG on the reduced matrix. However, this proved to be a problem because the switch to floats exploded the number of unique terms. I tried to round the loadings yielded by the PCA, but so far this seems to be a dead-end. What workarounds can I consider to tackle this problem?

I tend to believe that this is a well studied problem and I would be thankful for pointers and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $n$ documents $D=d_i, i \in 1:n$. According to Bayesian rule, following equation can be derived for a specific term $T=t$ and code $C=c$:
$$
\begin{align}P(c|t) &= \sum_{i=1}^n P(c,d_i|t) \\&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{P(c,t|d_i)P(d_i)}{P(t)} \\&= \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^nP(c,t|d_i)P(d_i)}{P(t)} \\&= \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^nP(c,t|d_i)P(d_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n P(t|d_i)P(d_i)} \\& \text{put } P(d_i)=1/n\text{ inside,}\\&= \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^nP(c,t|d_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n P(t|d_i)} \\\end{align}
$$
Where $P(c,t|d_i)$ is the probability of $C=c,T=t$ (among all the $(C,T)$ combinations) in document $d_i$, and $P(t|d_i)$ is the the probability of $T=t$ (among all the possible values of $T$) in document $d_i$. You can calculate $P(c,t|d_i),i \in 1:n$ and $P(t|d_i),i\in 1:n$ directly from your corpus, put them into above equation will get you the answer.

Hope it helps!